# Logged in and logged out user based on auth (navigation with Laravel & Vue)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using laravel authentication to decide what the user sees.

What I want:

- If a user is logged in they are able to access all the components through the paths in components.
- If a user is logged out they are not able to access all the paths. Only the default page I set them and the register and login path.

**master.blade.php**

```
@Guest
   <navigationloggedout></navigationloggedout>
   <p>Not logged in</p>
   <router-view></router-view>
@else
   <navigationloggedin></navigationloggedin>
   <p>Logged in</p>
   <router-view></router-view>
@endGuest
```

How do I only allow users to access certain vue pages when not logged in. And how do I set a different default path for a user that isn't logged in. 
The routes below shows the default component for a user if they are logged in.

**Routes:**

```
{
    path: '/',
    component: home_logged_in
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used router for auth check using router guard(https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/open-page",
            name: "openPage",
            component: OpenPage
        },
        {
            path: "/secure-page",
            name: "securePage",
            component: SecurePage,
            meta: {
                authRequired: true
            }
        }
    ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (!to.meta.authRequired) {
        next();
    } else if (store.getters["user/isAuthenticated"]) {
        next();
    } else {
        next({
            path: "/open-page"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand all the code, apart from the `store.getters["user/isAuthenticated"]`, are you accessing a getter that checks if a user is logged in or?

Comment: Any condition check can live there, as long as it returns a boolean. But in the case of the example you store in the state if user is Authenticated or not.

Comment: This is almost working perfectly, however when I go to the path '/' it doesn't run the `router.beforeEach`. Is this because I'm not going anywhere?

Comment: For example if I go directly to `example.com/#/`. Then it doesn't run the `router.beforeEach` even on refresh, while if I go from an `example.com/#/inspiration` to `example.com/#/` then it does run it.

Comment: That is strange, try using history mode(https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html).

Comment: So I'm using history mode now. I see that if I go to a url directly it never runs `router.beforeEach` while if I click on a button that `router-link`'s me to another page it does. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Ok I think I'll just use laravel's back end system to set up the authentication but thanks a lot for the help!